# ¬(p ↔ q) ⇔ (p ↔ ¬q)

Tags: logic

$$¬(p ↔ q) ⇔ (p ↔ ¬q)$$

I started with the left side.

$LS: ¬(p ↔ q)$

$\Leftrightarrow ¬ ((p → q）∧(ｑ → ｐ）） $       Biconditional Law

$\Leftrightarrow　¬（（¬ｐｖｑ）∧（¬ｑｖｐ）） $    Conditional  Law

$\Leftrightarrow（¬（¬ｐｖｑ））ｖ（¬（¬ｑｖｐ））） $     DeMorgan's

$\Leftrightarrow　（ｐ∧¬ｑ）ｖ（ｑ∧¬ｐ）） $              DeMorgan's

I am having trouble figuring out where to go from here.

Were there also any mistakes in any of my steps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\neg(p\leftrightarrow q)$$
$$\neg (p \to q \wedge q\to p)$$
$$\neg(p\to q)\vee\neg (q\to p)$$
$$(p\wedge\neg q)\vee(q\wedge\neg p)$$
$$(p\vee q)\wedge(\neg q\wedge \neg p)$$
$$(\neg q\to p)\wedge(p\to\neg q)$$
$$p\leftrightarrow \neg q$$

Comment: What did you do to get from:
(p∧¬q)∨(q∧¬p) to (p∨q) ∧ (¬q∧¬p)

Comment: Double Distribution, Negation, and Identity.

Comment: $${(a\wedge b)\vee(c\wedge d)\\=(a\vee c)\wedge(a\vee d)\wedge(b\vee c)\wedge(b\vee d)}$$

Answer (score 2):

So far: all good.

Next: use Distribution, Negation, then Identity.

Comment: How would you distribute:（ｐ∧¬ｑ）ｖ（ｑ∧¬ｐ）.

I know that p V (q ∧ r) <=> (p V q) ∧ (p V r)

Comment: So treat the first conjunction as one term.$${\color{blue}{(p\wedge \neg q)}~\vee~(\neg p~\wedge ~q)\\=(\color{blue}{(p\wedge\neg q)}\vee\neg p)\wedge(\color{blue}{(p\wedge\neg q)}\vee q)\\ =\ldots}$$Now distribute those two disjunction.  [Or you might use Absorption if you like.]